# how to apply mathematical operations between two array's identical elements(php)

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to subtract the wight and quantity of elements in two array if the **id** exist in both array.
first array called sales

```
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 13
            [name] => Rahul
            [sale_qty] => 2
            [sale_weight] => 38.00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 14
            [name] => shravandhika
            [sale_qty] => 1
            [sale_weight] => 12.00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => veena
            [sale_qty] => 1
            [sale_weight] => 19.00
        )

)
```

second array called returns

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 13
            [name] => Rahul
            [sale_qty] => 1
            [sale_weight] => 8.00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [name] => sree
            [sale_qty] => 1
            [sale_weight] => 22.00
        )

)
```

i'm trying to get  new array that have all id of the two array and sale_qty and sale_weight should be subtracted if the id exist in both array, means
the **resultant array should be**

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 13
            [name] => Rahul
            [sale_qty] => 1
            [sale_weight] => 30.00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 14
            [name] => shravandhika
            [sale_qty] => 1
            [sale_weight] => 12.00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => veena
            [sale_qty] => 1
            [sale_weight] => 19.00
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [name] => sree
            [sale_qty] => 1
            [sale_weight] => 22.00
        )

)
```

here the **id** 13's sale_qty and sale_weight are subtracted
and here is my try

```
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($sales); echo"</pre>"; //sales array
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($returns); echo"</pre>"; //return array
    $result_array = array();
    foreach ($sales as $salekey=> $salevalue){      
        foreach ($returns as $retkey=> $retvalue){
    
            if($retvalue['id'] == $salevalue['id']){
                $salevalue['despatch_qty']= $retvalue['despatch_qty'] - $salevalue['despatch_qty'];
                $salevalue['despatch_weight'] =  $retvalue['despatch_weight'] - $salevalue['despatch_weight'];  
            }
            
        }
        $result_array[]= array('id' => $salevalue['id'],'name'=> $salevalue['name'],'qty'=> $salevalue['despatch_qty'],'weight'=> $salevalue['despatch_weight']);
    }
```

this didn't give the all **id**s
please let me know the easiest and optimised method to do this

Answer (score 0):

sorry I'm also new to **PHP**

the method is almost the same as your script but I added **unset()** in some exceptions and some tweaks to my version :)

*below is the same script with the output you want :)*

```
//php 7.3.0
$arr1 = [
    [
        "id" => 13,
        "name" => "Rahul",
        "sale_qty" => 2,
        "sale_weight" => 38.00
    ],

    [
        "id" => 14,
        "name" => "shravandhika",
        "sale_qty" => 1,
        "sale_weight" => 12.00
    ],
    [
        "id" => 3,
        "name" => "veena",
        "sale_qty" => 1,
        "sale_weight" => 19.00
    ]
];

$arr2 = [
       [
        "id" => 13,
        "name" => "Rahul",
        "sale_qty" => 1,
        "sale_weight" => 8.00
       ],

       [
        "id" => 17,
        "name" => "sree",
        "sale_qty" => 1,
        "sale_weight" => 22.00
       ]
];

$NewArr = [];

foreach($arr1 as $key1 => $value1)
{

  foreach($arr2 as $key2 => $value2)
  {
  
    if($value1["id"] == $value2["id"])
    {
      $value1["sale_weight"] -= $value2["sale_weight"];
      unset($arr2[$key2]);
    } 
    else 
    {
      $NewArr[] = $value2;
      unset($arr2[$key2]);
    } 
}
$NewArr[] = $value1;
}

//output
print_r($NewArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could merge both arrays, and use the `id` key as the key for a resulting array.

Then check if the key already exists in the result. If it does not, add the item, else take the already existing item by id and subtract the values.

```
$sales = [
    ["id" => 13, "name" => "Rahul", "sale_qty" => 2, "sale_weight" => 38.00], 
    ["id" => 14, "name" => "shravandhika", "sale_qty" => 1, "sale_weight" => 12.00], 
    ["id" => 3, "name" => "veena", "sale_qty" => 1, "sale_weight" => 19.00]
];

$returns = [
    ["id" => 13, "name" => "Rahul", "sale_qty" => 1, "sale_weight" => 8.00],
    ["id" => 7, "name" => "sree", "sale_qty" => 1, "sale_weight" => 22.00]
];

$result = [];
$items = array_merge($sales, $returns);

foreach($items as $item) {
    $saleId = $item['id'];
    if (array_key_exists($saleId, $result)) {
        $result[$saleId]['sale_qty'] -= $item['sale_qty'];
        $result[$saleId]['sale_weight'] -= $item['sale_weight'];
    } else {
        $result[$saleId] = $item;
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [13] => Array
        (
            [id] => 13
            [name] => Rahul
            [sale_qty] => 1
            [sale_weight] => 30
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [id] => 14
            [name] => shravandhika
            [sale_qty] => 1
            [sale_weight] => 12
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => veena
            [sale_qty] => 1
            [sale_weight] => 19
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [name] => sree
            [sale_qty] => 1
            [sale_weight] => 22
        )

)
```

See a [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/LuSRV).